# Parent UIViewController Orientation Shouldn't Change After Dismissing the Child

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, presentmodalviewcontroller

Lets say I have three UI Controllers (A,B,C).

A is my root controller and inside the ShouldAutoRotate method I return YES.
I do presentModalView from A to B (B=>inside the ShouldAutoRotate method I return Portrait) then from B I do presentModal to C (C should be able to rotate to any orientation).

Now inside C I'm able to rotate the simulator to any orientation, and the whole View rotates perfectly.Here is the problem, when C is Landscape and I dismiss it, all the objects inside B will become messed up!! same thing happens to A.

I just need to have the rotation on C!!

Gratitudes.

Comment: I guess the rotation should be depending on each ViewControllers, One ViewController 's orientation should not affect another's because they are completly different code. Are you sure that your shouldRotate methods are perfectly written

Comment: I Just have "Return YES" inside it.

Answer (score 1):

In App delegate

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldRotate;
@end

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    if (self.shouldRotate == YES) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In viewController A,B

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).shouldRotate = NO;
    [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    [self shouldAutorotate:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In viewController C

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).shouldRotate = YES;

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES;

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (IBAction)closeVC:(id)sender {
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.shouldRotate = NO;

    [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    [self shouldAutorotate:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow all orientations from project info

[image]

and then override implement all these methods to target iOS 6 + in each view controller to enable and disable orientation.

```
supportedInterfaceOrientations

shouldAutorotate

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

Answer (score 0):

force rotate C to portrait before you dismiss it

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```