# Landscape mode in presented view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app in which only portrait mode is allowed. I am using a subclassed `qlPreviewController` for showing preview of an image. All orientations are allowed in this. But when I dismiss the preview controller in landscape mode , my UIView Controller's ui collapses. I i use following code in UIViewController's `viewWillAppear` method, My ui becomes correct.
if i use

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
     UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
     [c.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [self.navigationController presentViewController:c animated:NO completion:nil];
     [self performSelector:@selector(delay) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0 ];
}   

-(void)delay
{
     [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Can any one suggest the reason for this and a better method to do it

In order to restrict the app to only use portrait mode, I created a BaseViewController class as subclass of UIViewController and allowed only portrait mode in it. I created all other view controllers in the app as a subclass of this BaseViewController. Code in the BaseViewController is :-

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{


    return FALSE;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{


    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: can you not put your actual question description as code?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean "All orientations are allowed in this"? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the user can rotate preview controller to all oreintations. landscape or portrait

Comment: You said that your app only allows portrait. You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: But in qlpreviewController all modes are allowed. Please understand

Comment: Where did you come to that conclusion? Nothing I've read in the documentation says this.

Comment: Can you tell me how you restricted the app to only use portrait mode?

Comment: Click on your project, go to build settings, disable the layouts dont want (this is a slightly dated picture but its the same deal): http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Xcode-Project-Orientation.jpg

Comment: @Aggressor : Then rotation will be disabled on my QLPreviewController also

Comment: @user2885077 try this [solution] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28772144/4209418) set the code for ViewController A and B in your BaseViewController and set the code of ViewController C in your subclassed qlPreviewController